# $y(x)$ be a continuous solution of the initial value problem $y'+2y=f(x)$ , $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let , $y(x)$ be a continuous solution of the initial value problem $y'+2y=f(x)$  , $y(0)=0$ , where, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } 0\le x\le 1\\0 & \text{ if } x>1\end{cases}$$Then, $y(3/2)$ equals to
>
> (A) $\frac{\sinh(1)}{e^3}$
>
> (B) $\frac{\cosh(1)}{e^3}$
>
> (C) $\frac{\sinh(1)}{e^2}$
>
> (D) $\frac{\cosh(1)}{e^2}$

Integrating both sides we get , $$\int_0^xd(y(x))+2\int_0^xy(x)\,dx=\int_0^xf(x)\,dx$$

$$\implies y(x)+2\int_0^xy(x)\,dx=\int_0^xf(x)\,dx=1$$

$$\implies y(x)=1-2C$$where , $$C=\int_0^xy(x)\,dx=(1-2C)x\implies C =\frac{x}{1+2x}$$

Then , $y(x)=\frac{1}{1+2x}$ and so, $y(3/2)=1/4$.

> But no option match..Please help..

Comment: Solve the IVP over the interval $[0,1]$. Then observe that $y(1) = y(3/2)$.

Comment: If $y(1)=y(3/2)$ then how it helps? Where my mistake in my question ?

Comment: Sorry I misread the ODE, but the idea remains the same. First, solve the IVP over the interval $[0,1]$. Then compute $y(1)$. Using this value of $y(1)$, solve the other initial value problem on the interval $[1,3/2]$.

Comment: Use the laplace transform for problems like this.

Comment: @MrYouMath "Use the laplace transform for problems like this." No thanks (unless some sort of masochism is involved).

Comment: @Did It is almost a one liner. Left side ist $sY+Y$  and right side is the laplace transform of stepfunction minus a stepfunction with dead time.

Comment: @MrYouMath Do you think the OP can be made to understand this in one line? Then your lines are loooooonger than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all multiply both sides by the integrating factor $e^{2x}$ to get

$$(e^{2x}y(x))'=e^{2x}f(x) $$

Integrating both sides from $0$ to $3/2$ gives

$$e^3y(3/2)-e^{0}y(0)=\int_0^{3/2} e^{2x}f(x) \mathrm{d} x.$$

Using the initial data we get

$$y(3/2)=e^{-3} \int_0^{3/2} e^{2x}f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$

and I leave the evaluation of the integral to you.

**EDIT:**

As for what's wrong with your attempt:

- The integral $\int_0^x f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ is not always 1. This is true only if $x \geq 1$ which is unclear to me.
- What you denoted by $C$ is not a constant actually.

Comment: Ok...But why it does not come through my process ? Where my mistake ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 edited.

Answer (score 0):

`Solving the Part (1)

**$y′+2y=1 ,   y(0)=0$**

We get

$$y(x) = \frac{(1-e^{-2x}) }{2}...........................................(A)$$

Consider the Part(2),

**$y′+2y=0 $**

**$y(x)=Ke^{-2x}$**

**$y(1)=1/2*(1-e^{-2})$**  By the continuity find $y(1)$ from equation $(A)$

$ K=y(1)e^2$

hence

**$y(x)=y(1)e^2e^{-2x}$**

**$y(3/2)=sinh(1)/(e^2)$**

**$So$ $Option $ (C) $ is$ $ the$ $ correct $ $Answer$**

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: No question which would be more recent and that you could answer without duplicating an already accepted answer?

Comment: It is more simpler than the already accepted answer.

Comment: No it is not, just nearly unreadable.

Comment: Actually I didn't know how to type math symbols in math.stackexchange.com...This is the comfortable solution. If you do not understand the notations,let me know.

Comment: I hope, Now it is readeble...I request you to remove negative tag...